# Appengine wildcard URL issues

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, wsgi

I have a page in my Google appengine that needs to take records from the datastore based on parameters fed through the URL of the page. The URL of the page looks like http://example.appspot.com/page/WILDCARD/, where WILDCARD is a unique identifier (32-character hex string) for a record. It then takes the record specified by WILDCARD and displays it on the template `page.html`, or at least that's what it's supposed to do. Whenever I access the page as http://example.appspot.com/page/WILDCARD/, I get a 404 error. Does anyone know why/can anyone suggest reasons for why this might be? Thanks.

In my WSGI class handlers, I have

```
('/page/([^/]+)/', PageHandler),
```

and the `PageHandler` class itself is

```
class PageHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, recordID):
            allrecords = db.GqlQuery("SELECT RECORD FROM RECORDS WHERE recordid = :record",record = recordID)
            if not allrecords:
                self.redirect("../") #the URL is screwed up, so we're redirecting you back to the main page
            else:
                for row in allrecords:
                    template = JINJA.get_template("page.html")
                    self.response.out.write(template.render({ "recordtext":row.RECORD, "recordid":recordID }))
```

Additional details: `JINJA` is just the default jinja environment, I'm pretty sure there's nothing wrong with that. `RECORDS` is a `db.Model` type class that has members `RECORD`, a text property and `recordid`, a string property. It's currently not populated with any data.

**EDIT:** Nevermind, I solved the problem. It was my own stupidity when I simplified the problem down. It turns out that in actual implementation (i.e. the complicated version of this example), I had a tiny discrepancy between what I thought my URL was and what it actually was for /page/. Apologies.

Comment: could you link your app.yaml as well?  I think the redirect might simply not be put on properly there.

Comment: My app.yaml is pretty different from this simplified example, but the only lines in my yaml config relevant to this page handler are:

    - url: .*
      script: main.app
      secure: always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
webapp2.Route('/page/<recordID>/', handler=PageHandler)
```

for your route definition.

You can insert it along your other route tuples like:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', Homepage),
    webapp2.Route('/page/<recordID>/', handler=PageHandler),
    ('/otherpage', SomeOtherPage)
])
```

What you have might work fine as well with proper regex but I find it easier to read code when using template URLs defining expected paths and naming them.

See more: https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html

Comment: I actually use `app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([tuples of urls and handlers])` as my application definition, as used in the basic Appengine Python tutorials. Can you tell me how to use the above for a lot of pages/link me to a resource to use the above and/or modify that for use with the WSGIApplication method? Sorry, I'm a bit of a noob to appengine!

Comment: You can simply insert this line along your other tuples, see updated answer since apparently I can't write code here.

Comment: Hmm that's strange, the page still results in a 404.

Comment: @user3697240 OK... Do you have a handler for route '/page/'? If not, then you will get 404 when you enter invalid "recordID". To fix that you need to do `self.redirect("/")` instead of `self.redirect("../")`

Comment: Yep, I do have a handler for that page, but I'm absolutely sure I have a correct recordID.

Comment: Sorry but that's all I can think of without seeing more code... Everything here looks fine so it's probably something minor elsewhere. Can you also show logs with GET requests when you are getting 404?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I solved the problem. It was my own stupidity when I simplified the problem down. It turns out that in actual implementation (i.e. the complicated version of this example), I had a tiny discrepancy between what I thought my URL was and what it actually was for /page/. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

This what work for me:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
('/', Homepage),
('/page/.*', PageHandler),
('/otherpage', SomeOtherPage)
])
```